# I am having trouble understanding Polya's theorem and how to apply it to the following question:

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to color the vertices of a  3 x 5  card  (rectangle)  that is free to move in 3-space using m colors?

I am having trouble determining the rotations; I can sort-of understand the rotations for a square and triangle, but am having trouble with a rectangle, for some reason.  I am fairly inexperienced with this combinatorics class and would appreciate help with this homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you  say the rectangle is free  to move in 3-space  I assume you
mean it can be rotated and reflected. I also assume that you really mean the vertices (there are twenty-four of them) and not the subsquares (we have fifteen of these) which would be a different problem (which, incidentally, you may want to solve).

Therefore in order to apply PET  we need the cycle index $Z(G)$ of the
permutation group $G$ of the vertices which contains the identity, two
reflections and a rotation.

We  now  compute  the  disjoint  cycle decompositions  of  these  four
permutations.  The identity  contributes $$a_1^{24}.$$  The horizontal
reflection contributes only two-cycles to get $$a_2^{12}$$ because $3$
is even.  The vertical  reflection also contributes only two-cycles to
get $$a_2^{12}$$  because $6$ is  even. Finally the rotation  by $180$
degrees also contributes two-cycles only to get $$a_2^{12}.$$

It follows that the cycle index is given by
$$Z(G) = \frac{1}{4} \left(a_1^{24} + 3a_2^{12} \right).$$

Therefore the number of colorings with $m$ colors is
$$Z(G)(C_1+C_2+\cdots+C_m)_{C_1=1, C_2=1, \ldots C_m=1}
= \frac{1}{4} ( m^{24} + 3 m^{12}).$$

This sequence is
$$1, 4197376, 70607782701, 70368756760576, 14901161376953125, 
1184595336212990976,\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you for your help in clearing up my confusion!  I see what I was doing wrong and appreciate your input!